# Enter the Schengen Space if I hold an onward ticket

Tags: europe, spain, england

I was wondering if you could help me. I'll be going to England from January till June 2022 as an international student to study a semester over there.
My plan is to do a round trip from Madrid, staying there for about three days and then flying to England.  I'll later on go back to Madrid to go back to my home country.
As a non-visa immigrant, I know that I'm allowed to stay up to 90 days out of a period of 180 days in the Schengen Space.

My question is, if I hold an onward ticket to England upon my arrival to Spain, would I be allowed to enter as I have proof I do not intend to stay?

Comment: I think I got a little confused. Do you mean spend a week-end in Madrid in the middle of your stay in the UK? What's the concern here? That you have no ticket to go back to your country of origin? All of this is perfectly fine, the only requirement is leaving the Schengen area (both having the means to do it and not giving the impression that you don't want to do it). A week-end abroad for a foreign resident based in the UK is completely unremarkable (assuming you don't require a visa in the first place).

Comment: For completeness, what will your immigration status be in the UK? Will you have a short term study visa, for example?

Comment: Fwiw, important note for your Schengen entry - you would be a *visitor* there, not an *immigrant*. Intending to emigrate to the Schengen area would require a long-stay visa or PR, even if you would normally not require a visa as a visitor.

Answer (score 2):

If you satisfy all the conditions to enter the Schengen area (visa or visa exemption, finances, insurance, etc. and, for the time being, Covid-related requirements) then it is perfectly fine to go for a short visit from the UK or on the way there. Having the means to leave the Schengen area is one of the requirements and holding an onward ticket, while not strictly mandatory, is a good way to satisfy this requirement.

Note that what Schengen border guards care about is your leaving the area in time. It's perfectly fine if you have a ticket to any other country you have the right to enter. You don't need to have a ticket to your country of citizenship or ordinary residence.

Conversely, if you do not satisfy one of the requirements, having an onward ticket won't be enough to secure entry. For example, if you would otherwise need a visa, you cannot hope to get one in Madrid while in transit (and, in fact, the airlines wouldn't let you board if your planned transit is too long). Being based in the UK and flying from there also won't exempt you from any visa requirement.

Borders guards are also tasked with evaluating the purpose of your trip. If there are signs that you do not really intend to return to the UK or might actually be trying to immigrate in Spain illegally, you could conceivably be denied entry or detained until your flight back to the UK. I have no reason to think that it is likely but it's part of what the entry check entails.

Either way, the onward ticket is not the only or main requirement and will not change much to the decision.

Comment: After reading the question a few times, I think the plan is this:  Fly from home to Madrid in January, stay for a few days, fly to England, stay for five months, fly to Madrid, fly home.  The question therefore isn't quite about a "short visit from the UK."

Comment: @phoog That was actually my first interpretation (and the reason I wrote “from the UK or *on the way there*” at beginning, my first draft even omitted the first part and only included the “on the wat there” part) but I am not so sure anymore. As long as the visit to Spain is short and incidental, I think my answer is still appropriate. If anything, it's stopping on the way back that could raise questions (at that point you have an expiring British visa, you certainly want a ticket back home rather than to the UK).

Comment: Ah, I somehow overlooked the phrase "or on the way there."  Interesting.